# How to compare the values of listbox with a table values in c#?

Tags: c#, listbox, sqldatareader

I have values in listbox1, let say the values are hello, hammad, cricket. I want to compare this listbox with values in a table named oldTable. If I found the values in that table then //do something otherwise //do something else. I am using this code for comparing but this loop is not working correct.

```
while (sqlrdr.Read())
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= listBox1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString() == sqlrdr[0].ToString())
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);
            break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit For
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain *but this loop is not working correct*

Comment: forget this loop dear, it was some random stuff, if you have other solution, then post it,

Comment: I rollbacked your edit, Since you'll get help only if you show your attempt. so that people can think of how to fix that.

Comment: Multiple queries to the database? Why retrieve the entire dataset of oldTable. This could be very expensive if the dataset is large (>1000000).

Comment: Try to add a breakpoint to the loop and Debug.

Comment: sriram ok..
parth shah the dataset is not too large. it is only in 3 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need something like this. If this is not what you need then explain more clear what you're trying to acheive.

```
while (sqlrdr.Read())
{
    string tableValue = sqlrdr[0].ToString();
    bool found = listBox1.Items.Cast<object>().Any(x=>x.ToString() == tableValue);
    if(found)
    {
        //Search found do whatever
    }
    else
    {
        //Search not found do whatever
    }
}
```